# Disable Content Security Policy after a page has loaded

Tags: xmlhttprequest, content-security-policy, bookmarklet

I've got a JavaScript bookmarklet that prompts for a bookmark name, then using **XMLHttpRequest**, POSTs the name and current page URL to a Java servlet running in Tomcat on **localhost**. The servlet stores the name and URL in a DB.  This works fine for most webpages, but fails if the page that's currently loaded has added Content Security Policy "connect-src" restrictions.

Here's the error: *Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:8080/MyServlet' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'*

I obviously don't want to disable CSP completely.  And since I won't know if I want to bookmark the page until it's fully loaded, anything that tinkers with CSP in the response headers or *meta* tags is doing the work too soon.

Is there some way I can tell the browser to ignore the "connect-src" restriction for just my **localhost** case, or disable/enable it on either side of my **XMLHttpRequest** POST?

I'm in Chrome "90.0.4430.72 (Official Build) (64-bit)".

Comment: Simple way - use browser plugins to disable CSP for your own needs. Hardcore way - create a browser extension instead of JS bookmarklet.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "use browser plugins to disable CSP for your own needs"?  From what I've found, the ones in the Store simply remove the CSP restrictions that the page has defined when the page is loading e.g. remove the CSP response headers.  I don't want that obviously for security reasons.  Also, I won't even know whether I want CSP to be ignored until the page is fully loaded.  Is there a plugin that will allow me to disable CSP checking on a fully-loaded page?

Comment: Under "for your own needs" I mean that it'll work personally for you, and does not affect other users. It's not possible to disable CSP after page was fully loaded, but you can switch on plugin and then reload page without CSP.